# Visual Studio 2015 Update dependencies to latest version

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2015

Does anyone know how to update dependencies to the latest version?

I have created a web application using the default MVC ASP.NET 5 templates. It uses Bootstrap 3.0.0, but I'd like it (together with other packages) to be updated with the latest version. The current version of Bootstrap is 3.3.5, but I can't get the package to be updated when I right-click on the bower > bootstrap dependency and select "Update package". The output window from Bower/NPM shows this:

```
PATH=D:\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\iKnow\src\iKnow\.\node_modules\.bin;D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External;%PATH%;D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\git
"D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\Bower.cmd" update  bootstrap --force-latest --production
bower bootstrap#3.0.0           cached git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#3.0.0
bower bootstrap#3.0.0         validate 3.0.0 against git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#3.0.0
PATH=D:\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\iKnow\src\iKnow\.\node_modules\.bin;D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External;%PATH%;D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\git
"D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\Bower.cmd" update  bootstrap --force-latest --production
bower bootstrap#3.0.0           cached git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#3.0.0
bower bootstrap#3.0.0         validate 3.0.0 against git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#3.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Just open the file "bower.json" and change this line:

```
"bootstrap": "3.0.0",
```

...to:

```
"bootstrap": "3.3.5",
```

...and close the file.  Bootstrap will be updated automatically.

Also search _Layout.cshtml for bootstrap/3.0.0 and change it there as well (two places.)

Comment: This works but it seems a manual process. NuGet updates packages for solution/project at the click of a button. Is there something similar for bower?